# How to run Azure 2.2 project after installing Azure SDK 2.5

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-compute-emulator

After installing Azure SDK 2.5 (side by side with 2.4 and 2.2), I cannot run my 2.2 projects locally. I'm getting the following error:

> Windows Azure Tools: Error: The installed Microsoft Azure Compute
>   Emulator does not support the role binaries. Please install the latest
>   Microsoft Azure Compute Emulator and try again.

Looks like the compute emulator 2.5 replaced the 2.2 rather than running side by side.

I tried to install the 2.2 compute emulator, but i'm getting a

> A newer version of this product is already installed

Is there a way I can run both 2.5 and 2.2 projects on the same machine?

Comment: did you ever find a workaround?

Comment: @junichiro unfortunately no.

Comment: Wouldn't you just end up referencing 2.2 assemblies plus check assembly mapping in your web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upgrade the azure SDK the old compute emulator was replaced by newest one. You can run old projects by uninstalling newest version of the compute emulator and install the old version that is 2.2 version of the compute emulator. It is possible to build both version of projects at a time on same machine but debugging doesn't work. 
I think there is no way to run both version at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to upgrade your project?
You can try to upgrade your dll with "Nuget Packages". Pls go, Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Manage Nuget Packages for Solution > Updates > Update All (or jsut Azure SDK).